Unable to start Cassandra using EC2 public IP address
ON AWS EC2, I have updated the cassandra.yaml file with:
listen_address: <private_ip>
broadcast_address: <public_ip>
listen_on_broadcast_address: true
rpc_address: <private_ip>
seeds: <public_ip>

When setting each parameter to <private_ip> cassandra service starts properly, but with above config I am getting
failed to bind to <public_ip>
failed: cannot assign requested address

I even tried to keep the listen_address same as seed; as the node is seed node, but the error still stays. What should be done to make cassandra work with public ip as well?
(Right now it is single node, but setting it up such that it would be compatible with multi-node deployment)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Sure, I will post in DBA Stack Exchange next time. Thanks!

The error you posted indicates that you have configured the wrong public IP address so the EC2 instance cannot bind any services to it.
For what it's worth, you need to configure Cassandra as follows:
listen_address: private_ip
rpc_address: public_ip

and use public IPs for the - seeds: list.
If you are setting up multi-region deployments, you will also need to set:
broadcast_address: public_ip

so nodes can talk to remote nodes (in another region) on the public IP while reverting to private IPs when communicating with nodes in the same region.
If you need guidance, see the AWS doc on Working with IPv4 addresses to find the public IP for your EC2 instances. Cheers!

Thanks! I will try with the given updated configurations
